# Is this simultaneous equation model identified?

Tags: regression, self-study, econometrics, identifiability

I have a 3 equation simultaneous equation model where all 3 dependent variables depend on each other (i.e. Y1 is based on Y2 and Y3; Y2 is based on Y1 and Y3; Y3 is based on Y1 and Y2).

Would all 3 equations be identified in this below case?

Y1 = A0 + A1 Y2 + A2 Y3 + D1 Z1 + D2 Z2 + D3 Z3 + D4 Z4
Y2 = B0 + B1 Y1 + B2 Y3 + NONE
Y3 = C0 + C1 Y1 + C2 Y2 + E1 Z1 + E2 Z2

Note that Z1 is in both equations 1 and 3.
Note that Y2 does not contain any exogenous variables that are not in the other two equations.

I would guess that Y2 and Y3 can be identified. However, I am guessing that Y1 cannot be identified. In order for Y1 to be identified, would you need either Y2 OR Y3 to contain at least one additional variable that is not in Y1? (Is it OK for Y2 not to contain any exogenous variables that are not in the other two equations?)